# How to track progress when using System.Net.HttpClient for upload?

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using `System.Net.HttpClient` to do all the communication with a restful API in my iOS, Android and WP8 project.

One thing I am really missing: how to track progress when async uploading (posting) data to a server?

Any ideas? There are no events, callbacks or whatever in `HttpClient` that might be helpful to implement progress tracking.

One might think this is a standard requirement for all the mobile apps out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [ProgressMessageHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.handlers.progressmessagehandler%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) in here http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/5.0.0

Comment: This is a *very* good hint! The message handler is the key!